# How to avoid duplicate code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using jQuery to handle something. It relates to many class or id having a prefix 'receive' in its name. Now I want to duplicate those function, but with the prefix 'send'. It looks like this

```js
function onSelectAddress() {
    $('#receive-address').on('click', function() {
        $('#receive-dropdown').show();
        $('#receive-address').addClass('box-click');
    });
    $('#send-address').on('click', function() {
        $('#send-dropdown').show();
        $('#send-address').addClass('box-click');
    });
}
```

I don't want to copy paste and change 'receive' to 'send' line by line. Is there any way to handle this problem?

Comment: focus on readability of code - for such simple code, you'll agree the answers below are less readable than your code

Comment: What does your HTML look like? It might be more suitable to refactor that first, then the JS.

Comment: I am using partial in OctoberCMS. I pass a parameter 'send', 'receive'. Because in HTML, they are 2 select boxes with lots of information. I think the HTML is fine now. I want to optimize the JS code

Answer (score 2):

Refactor by creating a generic function which accepts a prefix:

```js
function doTheThing(prefix) {
    $(`#${prefix}-address`).on('click', function() {
        $(`#${prefix}-dropdown`).show();
        $(`#${prefix}-address`).addClass('box-click');
    });
}
```

Note the use of backticks for string interpolation.

Then use it:

```js
function onSelectAddress() {
  doTheThing('receive');
  doTheThing('send');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of to optimize your code is to create a generic function that takes a `receive` and `send` as a parameter and handles both cases. Something like(*code is untested but you get the idea*):

```js
function generic(prefix) {
    $(`#${prefix}-address`).on('click', function() {
        $(`#${prefix}-dropdown`).show();
        $(`#${prefix}-address`).addClass('box-click');
    });
}
// To use
function setupAddressHandlers() {
    generic('receive');
    generic('send');
}
// ...rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onAddressClick() {
  $('.address').on('click', function() {
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    $('#' + action + '-dropdown').show();
    $(this).addClass('box-click');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="receive-address" class="address" data-action="receive">Receive Address</div>
<div id="send-address" class="address" data-action="send">Send Address</div>

<div id="receive-dropdown" class="dropdown">Receive Dropdown</div>
<div id="send-dropdown" class="dropdown">Send Dropdown</div>
```

This code uses a common class "address" for both 'receive-address' and 'send-address' elements and utilizes the data-action attribute to determine whether it's a 'receive' or 'send' action. This way, you avoid duplicating the code and make it more maintainable.